# Input mask money in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I develop a web app using yii2,

My question is, how to make an inputmask money in yii2,
My code looked like this :

```
<?php echo $form->field($modelTools, "[{$indexTools}]harga_jual")
                            ->label(false)
                            ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
                                      ['class' => 'harga-jual',
                                       'mask' => '99999999']); 
?>
```

In past, I using js input mask by [RobinHerbots](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjetrKQlZHQAhVMRo8KHYWACnsQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FRobinHerbots%2FInputmask&usg=AFQjCNFPo0Go-uxuZClbf139itpH_-xgHQ&sig2=Y5jUUZ9s6IQkJyWeVHqF4A&bvm=bv.137904068,d.c2I).
I got problems, first : the class is not loaded, and second, How can I make this input like money format, like this 10,000 or 5,000 in yii2.

For the help it so appreciated.